# Response in the request-filter-servlet-jsp chain

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, http-headers, servlet-filters

I wrote a filter, but the result response does not contain the specified header. 

Is the final response is the same response, which was modified in the filter? 

What I need to modify to get a correct result?

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;//...

public class HeaderFilter implements Filter {//...
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "domain.com");
}//...
}
```

Comment: You are trying to set header after the Servlet has been executed. Please try setting the header before the doFilter method call. Just move the last two lines up above the doFilter line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You are trying to set header after the Servlet has been executed. 

Please try setting the header before the doFilter method call. 

Just move the last two lines up above the doFilter line."

That is the solution.

Thank you!